# Loop through line and highlight columns that are different

Tags: html, bash, awk, sed

I have a file and each two lines have an id which represents a 'key' followed by the other columns of data. The number of columns will ALWAYS be the same, however the data itself might be different in each column.

**File:**

```
1,ABC,XYZ,0,1,2
1,ABC,XYZ,0,1,3
```

I would like to categorize this data in following format:

```
    <td class="er">1</td>
    <td class="er">ABC</td>
    <td class="er">ABC</td>
    <td class="er">XYZ</td>
    <td class="er">XYZ</td>
    <td class="er">0</td>
    <td class="er">0</td>
    <td class="er">1</td>
    <td class="er">1</td>
    <td class="diff">2</td>
    <td class="diff">3</td>
```

I'm going to use the change in class to modify color and for the changes in data to 'stand out'.

I need some assistance on how to populate this html propery by parsing the data in the above mentioned file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F, 'function pr(x,y) {print "<td class=\"" x "\">" y "</td>"}
         function pr2(x,y1,y2) {pr(x,y1); pr(x,y2)}

         !(NR%2) {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if(a[i]!=$i) pr2("diff",a[i],$i)
                    else         pr2("er",  a[i],$i)}
           NR%2  {split($0,a)}' file
```

matches lines two by two